# Mapping image on spherical surface

Tags: julia, texture-mapping

In simple words i need to map a image to be use in a spherical surface. I being trying to do this for several hours. searching in google I din't find any proper solution (explained for dumb people).

I thinks the code from this link: 
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19712/mapping-images-on-spherical-surfaces-using-c is what i need. but (i think everything is alright) can make it work in Julia.

This is my code so far:

```
image = brightNoise(height,width,seed,rand=true)

arr = Array{Float64}(height,width)

function MapCoordinate(i1, i2,w1,w2,p)
    return ((p - i1) / (i2 - i1)) * (w2 - w1) + w1
end

function Rotate(angle, axisA, axisB)
    return axisA * cos(angle) - axisB * sin(angle),axisA * sin(angle) + axisB * cos(angle)
end

phi0 = 0.0
phi1 = pi
theta0 = 0.0
theta1 = 2.0*pi
radius = 50


arr = Array{Float64}(height,width)

for i= 1:size(image)[1]
    for j= 1:size(image)[2]
        #map the angles from image coordinates
        theta = MapCoordinate(0.0,width - 1,theta1, theta0, i)
        phi = MapCoordinate(0.0,height - 1,phi0,phi1, j)
        #find the cartesian coordinates
        x = radius * sin(phi) * cos(theta);
        y = radius * sin(phi) * sin(theta);
        z = radius * cos(phi);
        #apply rotation around X and Y axis to reposition the sphere
        y,z=Rotate(1.5, y, z);
        x,z=Rotate(pi/2, x, z);
        #plot only positive points
        if (z > 0)
            color = image[i,j]
            ix = floor(Int64,x)  
            iy = floor(Int64,y)
            arr[ix,iy] = color
            println(ix,iy)
        end
     end
 end
```

The `image` is just a black and white noise generated in Julia, i need to wrap a sphere with it.

Comment: This seems better fitted to Code Review than it does for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mandrill]

I have little idea what your code is doing, but fixing some of the indexing issues gives something that might help you get started. It looks like it's doing something spherical, anyway...

```
using Images, FileIO
mandrill = load(mandrill.png")    
height, width = size(mandrill)
arr = colorim(Array{Float64}(height, width, 3))

function MapCoordinate(i1, i2, w1, w2, p)
    return ((p - i1) / (i2 - i1)) * (w2 - w1) + w1
end

function Rotate(angle, axisA, axisB)
    return axisA * cos(angle) - axisB * sin(angle),axisA * sin(angle) + axisB * cos(angle)
end

phi0 = 0.0
phi1 = pi
theta0 = 0.0
theta1 = 2.0 * pi
radius = 200

for i = 1:size(mandrill, 1)
    for j = 1:size(mandrill, 2)
        # map the angles from image coordinates
        theta = MapCoordinate(1.0, width - 1, theta1, theta0, i)
        phi   = MapCoordinate(1.0, height - 1,  phi0,   phi1, j)
        # find the cartesian coordinates
        x = radius * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
        y = radius * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
        z = radius * cos(phi)
        # apply rotation around X and Y axis to reposition the sphere
        y, z = Rotate(1.5, y, z)
        x, z = Rotate(pi/2, x, z)

        # plot only positive points
        if z > 0
            color = mandrill[i, j]
            ix = convert(Int, floor(x + width/2))
            iy = convert(Int, floor(y + height/2))
            arr[ix, iy, :] = [color.r, color.g, color.b]
        end
     end
 end

save("/tmp/mandrill-output.png", arr)
run(`open /tmp/mandrill-output.png`)
```

Comment: Works fine. (I mean, at least runs) Thanks. But if I try with another image i get a 'BoundsError' error, trying to access to the index 1001 in a of 2000x1000 image. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: @exsnake you have to make sure you calculate the indexes properly otherwise you'll go out of bounds when you access the array. I don't know how you're calculating the indexes. You could use `clamp` while experimenting...

Comment: I just realize that the image have to be a square image. Work better know but i get some weird artifacts un the middle...I will keep touching the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @exsnake aye there's lots to do -- I may have got height and width mixed up (try `w, h = widthheight(img)`). There's lots of documentation for Images. Raise issues if you have problems, since it's not the most end-user friendly of packages... :)